# Need help figure out why I can logon to Windows with a revoked smartcard certificate

Tags: login, crl, smartcard

I am adding smart card login to our domain and have got almost everything working properly except that when I revoke the certificate on our Enterprise CA I can still log into computers.
I have checked that I can download the CRL using the link in the certificate and see that the cert SN is in the revocation list. I cleared the local CRL cache (using certutil -urlcache crl delete) on the client machine, and have now tested again 2 days later - still works

Can someone give some guidance on where in the logon process the actual smartcard certificate revocation list is checked?  Looking at this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/smart-cards/smart-card-certificate-requirements-and-enumeration#smart-card-sign-in-flow-in-windows it is just not clear to me who does what as it never says "check smartcard certificate CRL"

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When I looked at the properties for the CA Revoked Certificates group (the CRL) I found that the CRL Publication Interval was 5 years and publish delta CRLs was unchecked.  I change CRL publication to 1 week and enabled deltas at 1 hour.  Will see if that helps

Comment: Have you performed a packet capture to confirm that the endpoint is checking the CRL tcp/80? FYI there is a setting to control that. Typically used in a recovery scenario if CRL is inaccessible.